# which browsers are in scope for Tridion 2011 and Tridion 2013?

Tags: gui-extensions, browser

I'm beginning some work on some new Tridion GUI extensions and I'll like to use CSS3 and some HTML5 features.  I'm guessing 2011 was scoped for IE7, but is that true of 2013? Does Tridion use any polyfills, or feature detection?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following web browsers are listed as supported in the documentation for SDL Tridion 2013, under [Content Manager Explorer prerequisites](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_641A62725D8D454EA11EA256059CFADD)

- Internet Explorer 10.0
- Internet Explorer 9.0
- Safari 6.0 for the Mac
- Google Chrome, latest version
- Mozilla Firefox, latest version

I'm not aware of any polyfills or feature detection in use. This doesn't mean that you can't use them in extensions yourself of course :)

Comment: Dammit David, I just posted *exactly* the same thing, only to find I was some minutes behind you.

Comment: Apologies; Have a comment upvote on the house. If it's any consolation, Nuno has done that to me many, many times :)

Comment: Thanks David. Regarding the latest versions of chrome and FF, I saw in the config for 2011 that the browser version is hard coded in. Since Chrome updates pretty fast, it gets tiring when I see a "browser out of date". Will that change in 2013?

Comment: I understand your point of view, but no this will not change with 2013. You will still see a warning if you use a browser version that is not considered to be supported.

Comment: There's a difference between _supported_ and _tested_. The warning is there just to let you know that something _may_ not work, because we couldn't test it before the product was released.